# En mi página, la fuente de letra font-family: fantasy; solo carga bien en dispositivos de escritorio y no en móvil

Tags: html, css

Mi página es sencilla, hasta el momento solo he utilizado css y html para todo; yendo al grano:
Cuando verifico la página (está subida a github pages) en ordenador, me carga todo perfectamente, fuentes de letra, imágenes, todo, pero cuando abro la página desde un celular, los textos en las que debería estar esta fuente: "font-family: fantasy" no carga y en su defecto los textos aparecen con otra fuente que yo no designé, no sé por qué pasa ello.

Vuelvo y repito, la fuente de letra, carga perfectamente desde diferentes dispositivos de escritorio, pero al ver la página desde diferentes móviles no carga y el texto en cuestión resulta con otra fuente.

Así le agrego la fuente a mis elementos html desde mi archivo css:

```
.title, .card-title, .economiatitulo .modal-title{
font-family: fantasy;}
```

En la primera imagen: Este es el mismo titulo de la otra imagen, lo mismo, pero la página está abierta desde un celular, y así es como se ve, (ignoren los demás problemas, por ahora fijémonos en lo del texto del titulo que carga con otra fuente distinta a la que yo le designé)

En la segunda imagen:
Ese titulo "ignífugos" tiene la fuente que fantasy y como ven así carga en ordenador, simulando un móvil (por el asunto de responsive y tal) y sí se ve bien, no sé que estoy ignorando para que abierta desde un celular se vea así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si además de lo de la fuente, tienen algun otro consejo para la página que quieran darme, muchas gracias.

Página: https://comercializadoracreatex.github.io/

Comment: Hola. ¿Cuál es la fuente que quieres agregar exactamente y qué código estás usando para agregarla? Ten en cuenta que debes agregar todos los archivos necesarios, según se explique en la documentación de esa fuente.

Comment: ¿y el recurso de donde estas obteniendo la fuente esta en un archivo en tu server o es una direccion web? agregar más detalles sobre la fuente, archivos que venian en su zip, etc sería de utilidad para poderte ayudar. ¿probaste en el navegador movil usar la opción "visualizar en modo escritorio" ?

Comment: A parte de todo lo que ya te pidieron, si puedes poner la url de la web pueda que eso nos ayude a ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Hola,  muchisimas gracias por el tiempo que de alguna manera han utilizado en esta publicación, la verdad soy novato en esto entonces quizás no sepa exactamente q es lo que me dicen sin embargo según lo que entiendo:

La fuente que quiero agregar es "font-family: fantasy;" (fantasy) y la agrego a los textos que necesito de la manera convencional desde un archivo css, ya que me mencionan archivos, no tengo ni idea si se debe agregar algo más al proyecto, pero lo raro es que en ordenador si me carga la susodicha fuente, pero al abrir la página en movil, no carga

Comment: Esta es la página: https://comercializadoracreatex.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `fantasy` no es una fuente en concreto es un tipo de fuente genérica (como lo puede ser `serif` o `sans-serif`). Y lo deberías usar como *fallback*, es decir, como una fuente por defecto que se aplicará si fallan todas las fuentes anteriores.

En tu caso, no has especificado ninguna fuente, sólo el tipo genérico que quieres usar:

```css
.title, .card-title, .economiatitulo .modal-title{
  font-family: fantasy;
}
```

Esto puede presentar algunos problemas:

1. La fuente por defecto de tipo `fantasy` puede variar de un dispositivo a otro, por lo que el texto se verá diferente en diferentes dispositivos.
2. Si el dispositivo no tiene una fuente de tipo `fantasy`, utilizará la fuente por defecto del sistema que no será de tipo `fantasy` (porque no hay ninguna).

Ambos casos acaban causando que la fuente que se carga no sea la que esperas, pero en el caso 2 (que es el que estás experimentando) la fuente va a ser muy diferente a la definida.

Idealmente, deberías especificar una lista de fuentes y usar `fantasy` como último valor en plan *fallback*, es decir, como último recurso en caso de que ninguna de las fuentes especificadas funcione. Puedes leer más sobre esto en la [documentación de MDN para `font-family`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) (en inglés).

Mi **recomendación para solucionar este problema**: [carga una fuente usando `@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) y aplícala a los estilos del texto, dejando `fantasy` como último valor. De ese modo no dejarás nada al azar (o a la disponibilidad de la fuente en el dispositivo del usuario) y el texto se verá igual en todas partes.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Mi-Fuente-Fantasy";
  src:
    local("Mi-Fuente-Fantasy"),
    url("Mi-Fuente-Fantasy.otf") format("opentype"),
    url("Mi-Fuente-Fantasy.woff") format("woff");
}

.title, .card-title, .economiatitulo .modal-title{
  font-family: "Mi-Fuente-Fantasy", fantasy;
}
```